# How to retain function name from eslint Source Code?

Tags: javascript, node-modules, eslint

I want to store implementations of Javascript methods in a database. To store the function as a JSON parsed string, I am using the SourceCode module from ESlint. In my code, I have something that looks like this:

```js
 let r = require(file);
 mapObj.set(id, {
        id,
        fn: SourceCode.splitLines(r.toString()),
      });
```

This works correctly for function declarations, ie:

```js
function foo() {}
```

But for function expressions, ie: arrow functions, function expressions:

```js
const foo = (a, b, c) => {}
const foo = function(a,b,c) {}
```

it will not retain the function name and looks like this:

```
 "(a, b, c) => {",
 "  .....
  "}"
```

If this is a configuration from ESLint, I haven't been able to find it. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a function has a name, you can look for it in the `.name` property.

E.g.

```
 let r = require(file);
 mapObj.set(id, {
        id,
        name: r.name,
        fn: SourceCode.splitLines(r.toString()),
      });
```

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name

```js
const foo1 = (a, b, c) => {}
const foo2 = function(a,b,c) {}

console.log(foo1.name, foo1.toString());
console.log(foo2.name, foo2.toString());
```

Comment: This works, thank you.  I was hoping there was some way to configure the output globally to avoid having to conditionally check if a name property exists.